# Десериализация одиночки

Tags: java, сериализация, singleton

```
//Одиночка
public class MainList implements Serializable {
    private static MainList instance = new MainList();

    private MainList() {}

    public static MainList getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}

//Попытка "достать" объект
public MainWindow() {
    //Importing the latest version if it exists in path
    MainList mainListObj = MainList.getInstance();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        mainListObj = (MainList) oin.readObject(); //ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ//////
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Объект-одиночка класса `MainList` сериализован и хранится по адресу `path`.

На строке `//ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ`  объект успешно десериализуется в объект `mainListObj`, но он локальный. Как мне сделать его глобальным?

Я думаю нужно каким то образом обработать это в методе `getInstance`.

Comment: Посмотрите в Effective Java (2 или 3 издание), Item 3 и Item 89. Там, например, рекомендуют использовать `enum` с одним значением в качестве синглтона.

Answer (score 3):

Специально для случаев подобных сериализации одиночки существует метод `readResolve`, возвращающий что-нибудь другое, вместо того, что было прочитано методом `readObject`. Кроме того, всегда стоит рассматривать возможность переопределения методов `writeObject` и `readObject`, а особенно в случае одиночки. Например так:

```
class Singleton implements Serializable {
    private static final transient Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    private String value;

    private Singleton() {}

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        INSTANCE.setValue(getValue());
    }

    private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Singleton s1 = Singleton.getInstance();
        s1.setValue("One");

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(s1);
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        out.close();
        bos.close();

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        Singleton s2 = (Singleton) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        bis.close();

        assert s1 == s2;
        System.out.println(s2.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Например, вот так.

```
public class MainList implements Serializable {
    private static MainList instance = new MainList();
    private MainList() {}

    public static MainList getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

   public static MainList getInstanceFromFile(String path) {
    //Importing the latest version if it exists in path
    MainList mainListObj = MainList.getInstance();
    try {
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        instance = (MainList) oin.readObject();
        return instance;
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        return null;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: нет, здесь что то  не так